# no logo.png in /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-logo directory || changing boot logo in linux-mint 21 cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint

In the previous versions of linux-mint, 
I could change the boot logo just by replacing the `logo.png` file with my own custom logo. 
The directory was: `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-logo` 
But now it seems like there is **no** `logo.png` file in  directory and it has more than 66 of the same logos with different names (you can visualize by attached picture). And the names of the files are in a series like `animation-0001.png` to `animation-0036.png` and `throbber-0001.png` to `throbber-0030.png`. 
I really want to change the boot logo. 
Please help me with this issue and tell me which file should I replace with my own custom logo.
[image: screenshot from my file manager in the /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-logo directory]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's risky or not but I solved it just by replacing all the images with my custom png logo. 
 It was a little bit of pain but it worked. My boot logo is finally changed. 
I'll attach a photo of how it worked for me.
 [image: replaced all the existing logos with my custom ones]